# Flash CS4 export movie with nested movie clips

Tags: export, adobe-flash, swf, adobe-cs4

I want to export a Flash document to an AVI for import into Sony Vegas **with** nested movie clips playing as well (as they do in SWF). The export function doesn't seem to be capable of nested clips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found that I could do this is by exporting the SWF and using an SWF converter to save it as a video file. (I'd link a converter, but I'm still searching for something good)